# Backbone.js History.js url conflict?

Tags: backbone.js, url-routing, history.js

Are Backbone.js and History.js not meant to both be included in the same page?

I'm working in an environment where History.js is used, and for some reason it replaces all the URL hashes which my Backbone router relies upon.

Every `example.com/#hey/babe` is being replaced by `example.com/hey/babe` which obviously does not work well with Backbone hash routing.

Comment: Backbone's router and History object provide the same basic facilities that history.js does. Why are you trying to use both

Comment: Because I want to develop a Backbone app within an environment which uses History.js. That is, I can't remove History.js from the environment.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'm not 100% sure what is going on here, but I solved the issue by setting some options in Backbone's history object.

```
Backbone.history.start({ 
    pushState: true, 
    hashChange: false, 
    root: '/mysite/app/' 
});
```